# Answer exists and not posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: questions and answers.

In my question model:

```
has_many :answers
```

In my comment model:

```
belongs_to :question
```

When I post a new answer everything appears like it worked but it's never actually posted. In the terminal I get this:

```
Answer Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."slug" = 'hello' LIMIT 1
```

Here is the answer form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@question, Answer.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

In my view I have a counter that stays at 0 after posting an answer:

```
<%= question.answers.count %>
```

Comment: what about your view? could you include that in your question.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Yep ok, I added the form view.

Comment: Do you have a `question_id` in the answer table? Also, can you show the code that is meant to display the answers for a question.

Comment: you need a view that correspond with your answer. something like `<%= @question.answer %>`.I think...

Comment: How do you know it doesn't populate your database? If it doesn't populate the db, you've got an ActiveRecord creation issues, else it's a problem with lack of views

Comment: Ok, I posted the view and @Vasseurth yes, answers all have a question_id. I know it doesnt populate the db because the questions answers_count in the db stays 0.

Comment: should it be @question.answer.count? I'm not super familiar with simple_form but either your form or your controller is off.

Comment: No i believe answers.count is correct since question 'has_many' and i haven't changed the form from the beginning (posting an answer used to work). I'll continue looking for the problem though :) thanks.